# How can I prevent a graphic item from to be draw out the scene? and how to have different background colors for QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

I want to set up like the image bellow.

I want differents backgrounds color for `QGraphicsView` (say, same as window color) and `QGraphicsScene` (say, white). Also, I want that if some item is drawn out of the scene bounds that part is not rendered (the star 'any item' in img with legs cropped).

I have no clue how to set up this. I'm new on Qt.

PS: I'm using python, but you can examplify in c++ if you feel confortable.

[image]

---

**Answering Jeremy Friesner**

This is my code applying your tips:

```
    scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 256, 256)
    scene.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(scene.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Window)))
    scene.addRect(scene.sceneRect(), QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen), QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white))
    scene.addLine(0, 0, 356, 356)

    view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)

    self.setCentralWidget(view) # we are in a QMainWindow
```

As you can see, I add a white QRect using scene bounds and a line a bit bigger than the scene bounds. This is the screenshot result of my app (the line is drawn out the scene too):

[image]

If the app size is lesser than scene bounds (ie, `View <= Scene`), the part out the scene is not rendered (bc scroll bars doesn't allow), but if the app is bigger (ie, `View > Scene`), then it is drawn. How to solve that?

Comment: did you found your answer, or the answer below have solve it?

Answer (score -1):

> I want different backgrounds color for `QGraphicsView` (say, same as
>   window color) and `QGraphicsScene` (say, white).

A `QGraphicsScene` object is never directly shown on the screen -- that is to say, it is not a subclass of `QWidget` and therefore there is no way to add it to your window's widget hierarchy.  The only way to view the contents of a `QGraphicsScene` is by associating a `QGraphicsView` with the `QGraphicsScene` and adding the `QGraphicsView` to the widget hierarchy.

Given that, the solution to your problem should be to simply call `setBackgroundBrush(window->palette().color(QPalette::Window))` on your `QGraphicsScene` object.  The `QGraphicsView` will automatically reflect the background color of the `QGraphicsScene`.

If you then want the actual contents-area of the `QGraphicsScene` to be a different color (so that e.g. after you've zoomed out there is a window-background-colored border around a different background-color in the scene-area, as shown in your screenshot), you can get that effect by adding a `QGraphicsRect` item of the appropriate color and size (as given by `QGraphicsScene::sceneRect()`) to your scene.  (Be sure to call `setZValue()` on it with a negative value so that it will remain behind all of the other objects in your scene!)

> Also, I want that if some item is drawn out of the scene bounds that
>   part is not rendered (the star 'any item' in img with legs cropped).

AFAIK this is the usual behavior of the `QGraphicsView` -- any content that is outside the area defined by `QGraphicsScene::sceneRect()` is automatically clipped to that area.  Are you seeing behavior that is different than that?